# Google Maps API: reverse geocoding and address printing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I created a map with a bunch of different locations, each with a type of marker and a title/description. What I'd like to do is extract from lat/lng the relative address. I found [this function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=it#ReverseGeocoding) which should do what I'm looking for.. but I can't understand how to apply it to my existing code. Here's [**my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/7n1mwq3c/10/).

I'm looking for a way to output the address here:

```
infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>' + data.description);
```

Should be something like

```
infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>' + data.description + results[0].formatted_address);
```

Comment: You wrote "I found this function", what function is that?

Comment: ops, sorry. forgot the link. added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n1mwq3c/11/)

Call the reverse geocoder in the click listener for the marker, open the infowindow with the appended address when the callback returns successfully:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: data.title,
    // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
});
(function (marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': marker.getPosition()
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                infoWindow.setContent("<h3>" + marker.title + "</h3>" + data.description + "<br><b>address:</b> "+results[0].formatted_address);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
                infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + marker.title + '</h3>' + data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    });
})(marker, data);
```